# How can I determine the maximum number of pages a website should have for SEO?

Tags: seo, page, size

An SEO analyst interviewer asked me, "How many pages are there in a normal website?"

What is the exact answer for this question?

Comment: This StackOverflow question might help you:  [Is there a maximum size that web pages should be kept under?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430374/is-there-a-maximum-size-that-web-pages-should-be-kept-under)

Comment: I think your topic is about the maximum number versus your question which is the average number.  Maximum is probably irrelevant trivia, average might be important for SEO.  This older article talks about the average size of pages and the average number of objects.  http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/average-web-page/

Answer (score 5):

There is no maximum number of pages for a website in terms of SEO.

As far as SEO goes, your website should have as many *high quality* pages as you can produce that are relevant to your website's topic. Bad SEO comes not from having too many pages, but from having too many *low quality* pages.

StackOverflow is a great example of a website with many pages but great SEO. At the time of writing, [they have over 33 Million pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com) indexed in Google Search.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think they're testing how you think about sites.

A site can have as little or as many pages as it has the capacity to create depending on the hosting storage size. If you're working as an SEO Analyst you'll likely have service based clients that will have a few high priority service offering pages, content pages, and ancillary pages AND ecommerce clients with hundreds or even thousands of pages.

So the answer is there is no such thing as a normal site or normal amount of pages. Each site you work on will vary depending on the purpose of the site (informational, service offering-Lead Gen, ecommerce) as such, the amount of pages on the site will vary.